# Mysql innerjoin ( perhaps) with updated date as criteria

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have this requirement and I am using MySQl database

**Comment table**

```
id  user id  ariticle_id     comment        comment date
========================================================
 1     45        2           comment1          02/03/12
 2     45        2           comment2          03/03/12
 3     45        2           comment3          04/03/12 
 4     45        2           comment4          05/03/12
 5     45        2           comment5          06/03/12
 6     45        5           comment7          04/03/12
 7     45        5           comment8          05/03/12
 8     45        5           comment9          06/03/12
```

article table

```
id   article_text               article_date
============================================
2    Some text                  01/03/12
2    updated text               04/03/12
5    another text               03/03/12
5    another updated text       04/03/12
```

I want to fetch all the details userid,article_id, article_text, comment,comment_date from comment table and article table

for given article id =2 user id =45 with  details made after the updated article.

The expected output is like this

```
 user_id   article_id   comment           commentdate
     45        2           comment3          04/03/12
     45        2           comment4          05/03/12
     45        2           comment5          06/03/12
```

I am lost Please help, I am trying with the query in MYSQL

Comment: Well your article table need a column more, ie UpdateTime so that you can just store the time of update only. Please show us your query.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't contain any data in article table. However, `join` isn't that hard, you can find lot of examples out there from Googling http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Well Rohit in a database table design way , you are 100 percent correct , but Everytime I update the article , my system stores another record with the the new text. When I display the article the latest entry of the article is shown to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now, i think that i catch your requirement

but there are duplicate id in article table

after fix this, your can try with this SQL

```
SELECT  c.userid,
        c.article_id,
        c.comment,
        c.commentDate
FROM   comment_table c 
INNER JOIN article_Table a
ON     a.id = c.ariticle_id
AND    c.article_id = 2 
AND    c.userid = 45 

WHERE   c.commentDate >= (SELECT article_date
                          FROM article_date
                          WHERE id = c.ariticle_id )
```

Comment: Awesome,I works. I agree that there are duplicates( it is not really a primary key). Just wondering if it is the most optimized way. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2):

you should try to be specific with the id you are using, try this,

```
Select * from comment_table
join article_table on article_table.id = comment_table.id
```

Comment: Thanks for a very quick reply This will give me all the records, of article 3 and user 45 ,but  I need comments made after the article is updated ie comments made after 04/03/12 ( taken from the lastest article update for id 2 )

Comment: Your welcome. Well if you wanted a comment after the article is updated, then you can add a filter in your query, let me edit my answer. I'll get it quick.

Comment: just add this code after the last line, where comment_table.commentdate = comment_table.commentdate

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps:

```
SELECT  a.userid,
        a.article_id,
        b.article_text,
        a.comment,
        a.commentDate
FROM    comment_table a INNER JOIN article_Table b
           ON a.article_ID = b.article_ID
WHERE   a.article_id = 2 AND a.userid = 45 AND
            b.commentdate > date('2012/04/03')
```

Comment: Thanks for a very quick reply This will give me all the records, of article 3 and user 45 ,but  I need comments made after the article is updated ie comments made after 04/03/12 ( taken from the lastest article update for id 2 )

Comment: Well, this has to be dynamic you know what I mean , the example I gave only for explaining the problem. What if there are more records in the article table, the date should take the max of the entry with id 2.am I any close to being clear ?